# A question from Bob to Bob

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking, game, game-theory

**Set-up:**

John and Bob are playing a game that goes like this:

1. Bob is alone in a completely opaque, featureless room.
2. Bob chooses a question, though some types of questions are off-limits, which will be listed. After doing this, he cannot do anything else except speak until the game is over. The question must concern facts regarding only the next day.
3. John enters the room that same day and reads the question. Between step 3 and 4 (and only between step 3 and 4), he may do whatever he wants, except cause Bob's death in any other way than potentially making his answer incorrect.
4. John makes sure to be in the room two days after Bob made the question, and asks Bob the question Bob himself formulated.
5. Bob answers the question to the best of his ability. If Bob is correct, John will never kill Bob. If he is wrong, John will shoot him dead.

So, what questions are off-limits?

1. The question cannot have a paradoxical answer. So, for example, Bob's not allowed to choose the question "Is this sentence false?"
2. The question cannot be regarding a fact outside of John's physical power to change, or regarding a fact John is disallowed by the game to change. So, he can't choose e.g. "What is 2 + 2", or "What did you eat yesterday?"

There's an omniscient box there to tell them if John is physically and/or game-wise unable to change a fact with the time has. If he is physically unable, Bob must ask a new question. John and Bob are average men. Also, John perfectly understands exactly what Bob's words refer to; no ambiguities exist in his question.

**The puzzle:**

What question can Bob choose such that he guarantees that John does not shoot him dead?

Comment: If the game was about, say a hundred bucks, then I wouldn't need to ask: does John want to kill Bob?

Comment: @Bass The puzzle does not say, because you do not need to know in order to answer it.

Comment: How about "Are you within range of my gun?"

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain That would provide no guarantee. There are many ways Bob can possibly not be shot dead by John, but only one way (to my knowledge) he can guarantee that John doesn't shoot him dead.

Comment: It seems like there are a whole category of questions that allow John to change the answer, but can still be answered correctly.  "Are you wearing shoes?"  "Is there a lamp on that table?"  "What am I holding in my left hand?"
John can affect the answer to any of these questions, but it doesn't prevent Bob from answering them correctly.

Comment: Perhaps you are implying that Bob should be writing down both the question and the answer, and that the answer still needs to be the same when John asks the question as it was when Bob wrote it down?

Comment: I was thinking about answering rot13(Wbua: Nz v nyvir? Obo: Lrf.), but I'm not sure that should count because rot13(vs Wbua vf qrnq, ur pnaabg cebprrq jvgu fgrc 3 be 4), but by the rules of the game he should be able to, so this is kind of off-limits point 2?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain You are correct. That was not intended to be possible, yet it was made possible after I made some changes to the puzzle. Originally, John was nigh-omnipotent, but restricting his powers made the puzzle too complicated. When I made him human, I forgot to add the necessary rules to maintain the puzzle's intent. I will fix it now (luckily no-one has answered yet).

Comment: @DL33 Where is that from? I swear I've read that code before.

Comment: @user110391 you mean [rot13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13)? I personally use [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=rot13+Wbua%3A+Nz+v+nyvir%3F+Obo%3A+Lrf.) for it

Comment: @DL33 Ah, that's where it's from.

Comment: Is John allowed to dose Bob with psychedelics between step 3 and step 4?

Comment: @fblundun No reason he shouldn't be allowed to.

Comment: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7410/are-puzzles-with-the-correct-answer-being-unknowable-allowed makes me concerned that the intended solution to this puzzle is "it's impossible"

Comment: I don't think I will ever want to play games with John.

Comment: @fblundun Don't worry, it has a solution.

Comment: @Evargalo Well, I think playing with him would make you feel very alive ;)

Comment: What's the point of the limitation that Bob can't choose a question like "what is 2+2?" After all, John is allowed to make Bob drink so much alcohol that Bob is unable to answer "4".

Comment: @fblundun That would depend on how you read "to the best of his ability". It would be to the best of his current ability, but not to the best of his ability in general. In this case, interpret it in the latter way, or else the puzzle really is unanswerable, since John could just turn Bob brain-dead and have him answer in whichever way he wants. So yeah, when the time of answering arrives, Bob answers as good as his normal intelligence and knowledge allows. Any intelligence deficit he might have incurred will be magically reversed for the moment he answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bob could request John to ask:

> Did I mutilate myself yesterday in a way to make it totally impossible for me to ever kill you ?
>
>  Then Bob replies "No."

> If John proves him wrong, it doesn't matter, he won't be able to kill Bob.
>  If John concedes Bob is right, he has no right to kill him.

> Of course, John is obviously a madman, so he might as well kill Bob to cover up the evidence of his failure at this game.

Comment: In case anyone thinks this answer breaks the rules, here's why it doesn't: John mutilating himself only open up for the potential of the rules being broken (if Bob answers incorrectly). However, if it was disallowed to open up for the potential for the rules being broken, John could not do anything, because doing anything carries the risk of death. If John dies, the rules are broken. So, obviously, opening up for the potential of broken rules is not the same as breaking the rules. So, this answer works.

Comment: However, if John mutilates himself, and Bob answers incorrectly, then the game never ends due to incompletion. That is of no consequence to the puzzle however, because Bob still gets his guarantee that John won't shoot him dead. Good job!

Comment: I have a feeling that a few of us thought of questions like "Am I able to kill you?" but dismissed them because of the paradox rule. But that's not a paradox, it's a tautology.

Comment: @user110391 The rules stipulate the question must "concern facts regarding only the next day". This does not, it requires knowledge that John will never kill Bob at any point in the future. This requires knowledge of facts we are not allowed to ask about - it's effectively asking "On Day 2, did John make it so that he could not kill Bob on Day 3?" That does not concern "only Day 2".

Comment: It asks if on day 2 John did permanent damage on himself.  Damage that can not be repaired.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie The question must "concern" only the next day in the sense that it may only refer to the next day. Your interpretation would mean no questions are askeable, since every action has consequences. So, any question about the next day would be requesting information that can tell you about other days. Interpreting "concern" your way would be to interpret the puzzle unanswerable, meaning one can rule out your interpretation.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't think it's possible.

> John can put Bob into a medical coma the moment after he reads the question on Day 1, and can rouse him on Day 3 immediately before asking it. Bob has zero new information when coming out of the coma. He hears John read the question, which he already knew would happen. He knows that between 24 and 72 hours have passed since he wrote the question, but he already knew that would be the case, too. Whatever Bob thought the answer was when he wrote the question, he has learned absolutely nothing new that would cause him to change his response, yet John could have changed the correct answer at will.
>
>
> As far as Bob is concerned, *his entire universe* consists of John reading him a question. By Day 3, John can make it so that Bob has no memories, nor any meaningful sensory inputs, nor any source of information whatsoever. Bob can be reduced to a pair of ears with no input other than John's voice, and no memories or other sensory information with which to draw conclusions. Bob cannot know the correct answer when he is put into the coma, and it is impossible for him to recall or infer the correct answer when he comes out of the coma.

Comment: It is possible. I know of multiple solutions. It's just a tricky one. A hint is to break it down into abstract knowledge-restricting devices (so as to not distract yourself with the hows at first), and then take it from there. You are futher along this path than the other answers.

Comment: @user110391 What possible information can Bob base his answer on? He's a brain in a vat hearing a disembodied voice ask a question. He doesn't know anything about the world whatsoever. John is allowed to change the correct answer at will, and as far as I can see, is perfectly capable of blocking *every possible way* of Bob collecting information.

Comment: If I were to answer that, I would be answering the puzzle. I guess if no-one finds an answer across a long period of time, I will answer the puzzle myself (if that's allowed on this site).

Comment: @user110391 Self-answers are allowed, and I expect you're going to have to... so far the best answer is that it can't be done. How about one of the multiple solutions?

Comment: Okay, I will probably wait a while. I want to give people a good opportunity to get it.

Answer (score 2):

Brief:

- Day 1: Bob shares with John a question about day 2 of a fact that John can physically control. John leaves the room.
- Day 2: Nothing/Something happens.
- Day 3: John enters the room. John read the question to Bob about day 2.

The omniscent box said (if I got it correctly from comments):

> - John is unable to break the rules. So everything that could make John violating the rules is physically impossible for him. (Eg. take pills to sleep 3 days on day 2 or kill himself) 
>  - Also asking anything about if rules are (not) respected is forbidden. (ie. Is John following the rules?) 
>  - Bob is unable to measure time.

Solution:

> <s>John: Was John here on day 2?</s> (bugged as pointed out in comments)
>  John: Was this question asked to Bob from John on day 2?
>  Bob: **No**. *Then, **yes**.*

Explanation:

> Bob immediately answers **No**.
>  **If it is day 2** then John would not shoot Bob, he has no reason to do it as potentially messup/broke the 5th rule. At soon a second question is posed, Bob knows that John asked him on day 2, so the answer will be Yes from now on. On day 3 he will be left alive.
>  **If it is day 3** then John would not shoot Bob, because he is right.

> I add the additional constraints because if John can break the rules Bob survability is not guaranteed in any case.

Comment: I assume the question you refer to is "Did John visit the room on day 2?" This almost works, but John has a strategy against it. Firstly, John makes sure Bob doesn't have a way to tell time. Bob cannot do anything for the remainder of the game (except answer the question of course), so he cannot resist John taking his time-telling devices. Then, John shows up at day two, near midnight. Given your strategy, Bob would always answer no. John shows up, waits the few seconds it takes for it to become day three, and then legally asks the question. Bob answers "no" incorrectly and gets the glock.

Comment: fixed, i think..

Comment: Your new solution has good logic, but misses the dirty tactics John can use. It has gotten to the point now that it is unlikely for John to win, but it is still possible, and thus Bob won't have a guarantee. So, what can John do? He can give Bob something to wipe his memory. Alcohol is not difficult to get one's hands on, and for all Bob knows, John has access to drugs that are even better at wiping memory. So, if John does this Bob on day 2, Bob might not remember whether or not John asked him the question on day 2 or not. Thus, Bob does not get any guarantees with this question.

Comment: Based on the fact that my solution is based on a different puzzle at the time of my answering (eg rule 3 is different) and now John can do anything to Bob even with unguarantee success from John (eg. Force to drink alchol = wipe memory), my answer is no more valid.

Comment: How did my rewriting of rule 3 change the validity of your answer. I made sure that my rewrites didn't invalidate any answers.

Comment: As it was written it would implied to my understading that
John does whatever he wants -> Bob shared quest with John -> omniscent box is consulted to determine what John can do and in case reiterate -> day 2.
With new rules:
Bob shared quest with John -> omniscent box is consulted -> day 1 and 2 John can do whatever he wants and get any results (such drug or alchol), a litte above than the "average man" is expected to achieve.

Comment: I see, there was a typo where I wrote between day 2 and 3 instead of day 3 and 4. I thought that it being a typo was pretty obvious though, as the puzzle would be trivial to solve if the typo was correct. Furthermore, the original, incorrect wording didn't say John couldn't do what he wanted later on, so my rewrite actually limited John's powers.

Answer (score 1):

> John: "Who won the baseball game that occurred between steps 3 and 4?"

> Bob, answering *to the best of his ability*: "I don't know."

Comment: That is not an answer to the question, but rather a response. To answer a question is to attempt to provide the information requested by the question. A question does not (explicitly at least) ask for whether or not you know the answer to it; a question asks for the answer. Saying "I don't know" is thus not answering the question, and is thus not within the game.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> "Is John alive?"

Comment: I answered that too (except with "Are you"), but then realized it was effectively the same as DL33's comment, not just similar.

Comment: This is a question John is unable to affect within breaking the rules. If he dies, he can't enter the room on day 3 and ask Bob the question, which is a part of the game.

Comment: Furthermore, your question is not regarding day 2, but instead, regarding the present, which would be day 3.

Comment: @user110391 "If he dies, he can't enter the room on day 3" The current formulation does not require that; he can "make sure to be there" by killing himself in the room (or have someone else bring his corpse. Being able to ask the question while dead seems the bigger problem.

Comment: @Retudin You are right given your reading, but the point still stands. Another reading would say that **he** is not there if he's dead, it's just his body.